# how to use other projects own global variable or static member variable in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

sorry that my english skill is baddest.

when i use c# , i dont't crazy global variable ( no problems used otehr projects static variable in member   but when use static variable in MFC ,

i have a problem neither global variabel or static member  variable
problem too , it's  LNK2019 and LNK2001  unreserved external symbols error .

when i use static variable  i have declared of members

- .h Source *

  ```
  #pragma once
  #include "../CUstomCtl/CUstomCtlDlg.h"

  extern CCUstomCtlDlg CusDlg; // this declaration is  when i use for 
                               // global variable
  class CGlobalClass
  {
   public:
   CGlobalClass(void);

  ~CGlobalClass(void);

   //static CCUstomCtlDlg CusDlg;  // i want CusDlg use to other project 
                                   // like static varialble
  };
  ```
- .cpp Source *

  ```
     #pragma once
     #include "StdAfx.h"
     #include "GlobalClass.h"
     #include "../CUstomCtl/CUstomCtlDlg.h" // CCUstomCtlDlg included


    CCUstomCtlDlg CusDlg = NULL; // declared like this

    CGlobalClass::CGlobalClass(void)
    {
    }


    CGlobalClass::~CGlobalClass(void)
    {
    }
  ```

  // i use in other project global variable like this

  ```
     #include "../MyGlobal/GlobalClass.h" // i had a include

    void CtestDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
    {
       // TODO: 여기에 컨트롤 알림 처리기 코드를 추가합니다.

       CusDlg.DoModal(); // LNK error !! crazyed me .
    }
  ```
- i want know Two case in MFC *

1. using in global variable to other project not own project
2. using in static member variable to other project not own project

please help me my head will be explosion soon .

Comment: Before you ask a question like this, you first priority should be to figure out what language you are in, because you seem confused. "*java c# c++ c mfc*"

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do a global variable

.h source

```
extern CCUstomCtlDlg CusDlg;
```

.cpp source

```
CCUstomCtlDlg CusDlg;
```

This is how to do a static class variable

.h source

```
class CGlobalClass
{
    static CCUstomCtlDlg CusDlg;
};
```

.cpp source

```
CCUstomCtlDlg CGlobalClass::CusDlg;
```

Comment: thanks your answers , when use other project this global or static variable occurred LNK  error , so i crazy ^^

Comment: @Theremin Then you made a mistake somewhere else. Because the code above is how you do it. Why don't you try first on a very small project, until you are confident you know how to do this. Then you can try the same technique on a larger project.

Comment: @Theremin Your code for the global variable is wrong. Can you see the difference between your code and my code?

Comment: i have a lot of career with MFC  but using MFC is long time no see , sorry my skill is bad.^^

Comment: yes . i want show your code , i will have reserved my codes to learn *^^*

Comment: i have no problem using own project but when i use other project occurred this problems .  why ??

Comment: @Theremin That's impossible for me to say,

Comment: sorry  i had don't know this is your answer code .     my questions' source is repaired. but i wonder why own project is no problem but when i use the another project occurred LNK ERROR , i set path include header file.

Comment: @Theremin Please post the **exact** error message. Include paths are nothing to do with linker errors.

Comment: i  make a new project named  MyDlg  error is 1>GlobalClass.obj : error LNK2019: "public: __thiscall CMyDlgDlg::CMyDlgDlg(class CWnd *)" (??0CMyDlgDlg@@QAE@PAVCWnd@@@Z) 외부 기호(참조 위치: "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'public: static class CMyDlgDlg CGlobalClass::myDlg''(void)" (??__E?myDlg@CGlobalClass@@2VCMyDlgDlg@@A@@YAXXZ) 함수)에서 확인하지 못했습니다.
1>C:\Users\ABC\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\test\Debug\MyGlobal.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1개의 확인할 수 없는 외부 참조입니다.
1>

Comment: why error occurred in CMyDlgDlg Constructor ??

Comment: @Theremin Because that error message is about a missing constructor definition, not about a static or global variable.

Comment: @Theremin The missing deifnition is for `CMyDlgDlg::CMyDlgDlg(CWnd *)`.

Comment: Constructor is auto implemented . CMyDlgDlg::CMyDlgDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
 : CDialogEx(CMyDlgDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
 m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

Comment: #include "../MyGlobal/GlobalClass.h" // .declared header  and i am call void CtestDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
 // TODO: 여기에 컨트롤 알림 처리기 코드를 추가합니다.
 
 CGlobalClass::myDlg->DoModal();
}

Comment: now error is Two one is :  모든 출력이 최신 상태입니다.
2>testDlg.obj : error LNK2001: "public: static class CMyDlgDlg * CGlobalClass::myDlg" (?myDlg@CGlobalClass@@2PAVCMyDlgDlg@@A) 외부 기호를 확인할 수 없습니다.
2>C:\Users\ABC\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\test\Debug\test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1개의 확인할 수 없는 외부 참조입니다.

Comment: two is : GlobalClass.obj : error LNK2019: "public: __thiscall CMyDlgDlg::CMyDlgDlg(class CWnd *)" (??0CMyDlgDlg@@QAE@PAVCWnd@@@Z) 외부 기호(참조 위치: "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'public: static class CMyDlgDlg * CGlobalClass::myDlg''(void)" (??__E?myDlg@CGlobalClass@@2PAVCMyDlgDlg@@A@@YAXXZ) 함수)에서 확인하지 못했습니다.
1>C:\Users\ABC\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\test\Debug\MyGlobal.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1개의 확인할 수 없는 외부 참조입니다.

Comment: Thank you john very helpful. Thank you. I will be stutying this error.  Good luck friend.~